# Is there any way to configure jboss to clear the ThreadLocal variables at the end of execution of the thread?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, threadpool, jboss5.x, thread-local

I am deploying a web application under **Jboss AS 5.1.0.GA** and in my application, I'm using some `java.lang.Threadlocal` variables. By definition, `java.lang.Threadlocal` variables should be cleared by end of execution of the thread. In case of Application server, since its using a **thread pool**, the `java.lang.Threadlocal` variables are not cleared.

Do you know how to configure `Jboss AS 5` to clear these **java.lang.Threadlocal** varibles? I already googled for that and i didn't find anything interesting. I am looking for a solution for **Jboss 5** and not **Jboss 6**.

Comment: Is it a webapp or EJBs? If it is a webapp you should be able to add a ServletFilter that clears it.  For EJBs I think there is some support for interceptors.

Comment: it is a webapp, i don't think that the developer has to manage this. If i use deploy my app under `tomcat` i don't have any problem, the variables are cleared/nullify thats why i am looking to configure this (in a xml file for example)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any logging from jboss as to why the threadlocal cannot be removed? I would be surprised if such an issue is present.

Comment: No there is no error in jboss server log, i already verified.

Comment: You could try adding a log statement to the remove method of the threadlocal that is not cleaned up. That way you're really sure that the cleanup doesn't happen. If this is the case, start by logging a bug report at jboss side and see if they have a workaround.

Comment: This already appears to be fixed in 4.2.3, unless I'm mis-reading the bug report. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8389 It even has the same wording as used by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can create ContextListener and override onContextDestroyed or create servlet and override destroy method, in overriden methods clean up your threads

Comment: I don't think that the developer has to manage this. If i use deploy my app under `tomcat` i don't have any problem, the variables are cleared/nullify thats why i am looking to configure this (in a xml file for example)